# Changing background of an element through jQuery : ColorPicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

I am using ColorPicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js in my html page.

I have set the ColorPicker to a `<span>` tag. When I click on the `<span>` tag, the ColorPicker dropdown is displayed, and programmatically set the background of the `<span>` tag to the selected color from the pallete through the onChange function provided by ColorPicker.js.

The problem I am facing is, when I am dynamically generating a form from jquery by cloning some fields, I am also cloning the `<span>` tag on which I have used the ColorPicker. When I try to change the color, I am logging the element in console, and the background color is set properly to the `<span>` tag, but when I inspect the element, I do not see any changes in the `<span>` tag.

The same code works properly, when I edit the already saved form and then try to change the color. But when I dynamically generate the form, the code doesn't work.

Below is the element whose background I need to change:

```
<span>
    <span class="colorPickerBtn widgetFontColor" style="width: 178px" >
        Font Color </span>
</span>
```

Below is the ColorPicker function which changes the background of the above `<span>` tag:

```
$('.widgetFontColor').ColorPicker({

     onBeforeShow: function (colpkr) {

        var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
        ctx.strokeStyle = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
        var hexColor = ctx.strokeStyle;
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(hexColor);

     },
     onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,ele){

     $(ele).parents('.forColor').find('.layoutColor').val('#' + hex);
     $(ele).parent().addClass("is-dirty"); 
     $(ele).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex );

     console.log(ele);  
    },
    onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {

        $(el).parents('.forColor').find('.layoutColor').val('#' + hex);
        $(el).ColorPickerHide();
    }
 });
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here. Or do I need to do something in onChange so that changes will be reflected?

Comment: Not sure if this is the case for you but a common issue that comes up with dynamically generated elements and events is that the newly generated elements have not been initialized with widgets or event handlers.

This can happen if the javascript runs on page load, then the elements are generated and have not been initialized because they got added after the javascript runs.

It is a little unclear what problem you are trying to solve because you mention the color changes but when you inspect it doesn't look right. 
What does that mean?

Comment: @Allen: In the console.log() in above example, I can see the expected changes in the <span> tag in console, but when I inspect the element, the changes aren't reflected over there and its the same span as above.

Comment: And talking about Event Handlers, I do get the ColorPicker pallete on clicking the <span> tag. So I don't think event handler should be the issue. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would have to agree with you, if you are able to get the picker on clicking the span that the issue is not in binding the picker after dynamic generation of elements.